# "DB Error: Syntax error" - after using false "find and merge duplicate" rule

Tags: error-page, civirules, error

I've tested the following steps on the CiviCRM Demo...

[image: CiviCRM Demo rule]

...I've mistakenly filled in no fields and that's the message I've got, after I've used the rule.

[image: CiviCRM Demo Error Message]

So, if I cannot delete or edit the rule, how can I solve the problem??
After this, I'm not able to add a new inidividual...

Help, please!

Answer (score 2):

Since you marked it as Reserved you cannot modify or delete it.  (It can be gotten rid of by directly modifying the database, but I think that is the only way.)

Your best bet is to ignore it, and create a new rule that you can use.  Just don't mark it as Reserved until you are sure that it is defined as you wish.

Note that you can edit the name and usage type, so you could rename it "DO NOT USE" and make it a General rule.

Comment: I cannot only ignore that rule... because it's the reason that there's no way to add new individuals. Now it only show's error messages.